# Couple of linear regressions with heteroskedasticity and correlated errors

Tags: regression, least-squares, heteroscedasticity

I have two linear models:

$$
y_1 = \mu_1 + \beta_1x + \epsilon_1
$$
$$
y_2 = \mu_2 + \beta_2x + \epsilon_2
$$

where $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \sim \text{MVN}(0, \Sigma(x))$, where $\Sigma(x)$ in NOT diagonal.

At the moment I'm regressing $y_1$ and $y_2$ on $x$, then I'm calculating the squared residuals $\epsilon_1^2$, $\epsilon_2^2$ and $\epsilon_1\epsilon_2$ and I'm regressing them linearly on $x$:

$$
\epsilon_1^2 = \mu_3 + \beta_3x + z_1
$$
$$
\epsilon_2^2 = \mu_4 + \beta_4x + z_2
$$
$$
\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 = \mu_5 + \beta_5x + z_3.
$$

What I need are estimates of all the $\mu$s and $\beta$s. I think that I'm losing efficiency in both regressions (because of the heteroskedasticity in the first and the chi-squared distributed error in the second). Is there any computationally cheap way to improve things?

Comment: The structure of $\Sigma(x)$ is unknown, I suppose that in my problem it is close to linear. From some plots it looks like a linear fit is not too bad, even though there are some important outliers which are quite problematic.

Comment: How much heteroskedasticity is there (roughly, $\max \sigma_i / \min \sigma_i$ as a guess?  If it's less than about 3 or so, the efficiency loss is pretty small, or so I was taught as a rule of thumb...

Comment: The heteroskedasticity is moderate, but my estimates are suffering because of some big outliers (several standard deviations away from the regression line).